# Kafka Mongodb Sink Connector - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: mongodb, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am trying to set up a mongodb sink connector but I am getting an error when I start it

error:

```json
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nConfiguration is not defined: topic\nUnable to connect to the server.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

digging further in the log files I found those two errors:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

my systemd configuration:

confluent-kafka-connect.service

```
[Install]
Environment=KAFKA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/mongo-ssl/mongodb_ca.ts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxx -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/var/mongo-ssl/keystore.pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxx"
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

curl command

```sh
curl --noproxy "*" -k -X PUT https://xx.xx.xx:8443/connectors/kafka-connect-sink-mongo-test/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' {

        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
        "writemodel.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneBusinessKeyTimestampStrategy",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "group.id": "kafka_connect",
        "transforms": "WrapKey",
        "field.renamer.regex": "[]",
        "topic.override.sourceB.document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneBusinessKeyTimestampStrategy",
        "field.renamer.mapping": "[]",
        "database": "xxx",
        "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "transforms.WrapKey.field": "xxx",
        "transforms.WrapKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Key",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.projection.list": "xxx",
        "topics": "xxx",
        "max.num.retries": "3",
        "delete.on.null.values": "false",
        "collection": "xxx",
        "topic.override.sourceB.collection": "xxx",
        "change.data.capture.handler": "",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xxx:8081/schema/",
        "connection.uri": "mongodb://xxx:xxx@some.url:port/xxx?ssl=true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "max.batch.size": "0",
        "post.processor.chain": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder",
        "retries.defer.timeout": "5000",
        "rate.limiting.timeout": "0",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xxx:8081/schema/",
        "rate.limiting.every.n": "0",
        "value.projection.type": "whitelist"
   
}'
```

logs

```
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:551)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:433)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:273)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:257)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:331)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1688)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:1010)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1079)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:765)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:430)
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: ... 9 more
Jan  7 10:42:52 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx connect-distributed: Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

and I am using [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-configure-ssl) documentation to create the key and trust strores

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: This error could be a lot of different things .. Not sure if you can enable debugging in kafka by setting `-Djavax.net.debug=all` Also make sure that the connection URL matches the CN or alt name in the SSL certificate presented by mongo?  Are you also using client certificate authentication?